# Delete row from scipy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a scipy sparse matrix `data` and an integer `n` which corropsonds to a row in `data` which I want to delete. To delete this row I tried this:

```
data = sparse.csr_matrix(np.delete(np.array(data),n, axis=0))
```

However, this produced this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 260, in <module>
    X_labeled = sparse.csr_matrix(np.delete(np.array(X_labeled),n, axis=0))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._set_self(self.__class__(coo_matrix(arg1, dtype=dtype)))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 177, in __init__
    self.row, self.col = M.nonzero()
SystemError: <built-in method nonzero of numpy.ndarray object at 0x113c883f0> returned a result with an error set
```

When I run:

```
data = np.delete(data.toarray(),n, axis=0)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 261, in <module>
    X_labeled = np.delete(X_labeled.toarray(),n, axis=0)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4839, in delete
    "size %i" % (obj, axis, N))
IndexError: index 86 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

When I run this:

```
print(type(data))
print(data.shape)
print(data.toarray().shape)
```

I get this:

```
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
(4, 2740)
(4, 2740)
```

Comment: What does you data look like? Running your line with this simple data works: `data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`.

Comment: The right way to turn a sparse matrix into a dense array is `data.toarray()`

Comment: Why not index `data` with all row indices except the one want to delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to turn a sparse matrix into a dense one is with `toarray`, not `np.array(...)`:

```
In [408]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(np.eye(3))
In [409]: M
Out[409]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [410]: np.array(M)
Out[410]: 
array(<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

This is a single element object dtype array that contains the sparse matrix - unchanged.

```
In [411]: M.toarray()
Out[411]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

`delete`  works with this correct array:

```
In [414]: data = sparse.csr_matrix(np.delete(M.toarray(),1, axis=0))
In [415]: data
Out[415]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [416]: data.A
Out[416]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Indexing will do the same thing:

```
In [417]: M[[0,2],:]
Out[417]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [418]: _.A
Out[418]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
In [420]: M[np.array([True,False,True]),:].A
Out[420]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

I would guess that the indexing route is faster, but we'd have to do time tests on realistic size arrays to be sure.

Internally `delete` is rather complex, but for some inputs it does something like this - constructing a boolean array with `False` for the rows you want to delete.

---

making the boolean mask:

```
In [421]: mask=np.ones((3,),bool)
In [422]: mask[1]=False
In [423]: M[mask,:].A
```

Comment: I think you mean `todense()`method.. ah nevermind it's not about matrices anyways

Comment: `todense` makes a `np.matrix`, `toarray` makes an `np.ndarray` (with a `.A` short cut).